# Python based dynamic value substitution Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I have a table with example values as below:
[The total sum of all the values in Column T1 should always be 300. 
The values of Column A are constant and never change. 
The Values of Column B always lies between 1 and 2.
The values in column T2 is product of T1, A and B.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpMg9.png)

[Now I want to substitute new values in T1 and B such that the total sum of values in T1 remains 300, Column B dose'nt change from before and new values are substituted in column B such that Total sum of Column T2 is maximum. Below is a random example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRnjw.png)

Can I write an automatic python script that keeps the assumption that Total of T1 is 300, values in B change but always lie between 1 and 2 such that total sum of the column T2 is maximum?

Comment: This sounds a lot like an assignment... Have you tried anything? The short answer is "yes, you could write something like that".

Comment: Hey, the question I posted is just an example. I actually am working with data thats thousands of rows long and a lot more columns! I did write a python script that manually inserts values with above constraints! Was wondering if there is a smarter way to do it.

Comment: We don't know what  you did or how you did it, so can't suggest improvements.